# C++ Profiler on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, profiler

I'm at the beginning with C++ and sometimes I don't know how much my compiler will like two different implementation of an alghoritm. 
Is there a *simple* tool I can use to see how much time takes my code to execute?

EDIT: Im using gcc compiler

Comment: Use the high precision timer to time your code doing your algorithm 1000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mesure how long the entire program run's, then Code-Blocks/Visual studio should
tell you when the program closes. It should be in the log at the bottom.

If you want to mesure how long a specific line, or function takes, I would suggjest researching
`clock()` or `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` and how to use them.

the `clock()` function is slow, but it's easyer to use. an example:

```
float start_time = clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
func();
float end_time = clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
float dtime = start_time - end_time;
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that `clock` does something different on Windows than on Unix (Linux, MacOS, etc). It makes little difference if your code is just plain code, but if you do I/O or otherwise cause the system to run something else, in Windows, `clock` gives the total time the code ran, where in Unix it gives the CPU-time consumed by the program - so something doing 10 seconds of file-I/0 may come out as `0.02s`, because that's how much of the time was actually the CPU-time, but it took 10 seconds "real time".

Answer (score 7):

**Free**

- [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/)
- [Proffy](http://www.pauldoo.com/proffy/)

**Not Free**

- [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/codeanalyst-archive/)
- [Intel VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe)
- [Semantic Designs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CppProfiler.html)

Comment: Google Test does profiling?!

Answer (score 2):

I have had very good experience with AQtime from Smart Bear, it is not free, but you can get a free trial. It integrates really well into Visual C++ and RAD Studio from Embarcardero.

http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling

The data is easily accessible in the IDE, and especially the hit count and time spent numbers in the gutter section, next to the line numbers is useful.